# Wordpress changing page adress

Tags: wordpress

For some reason 1 page has different URL than all the others.

Its `domain.com/en/page-name` whereas WordPress shows it should be `domain.com/page-name`, this leads to that page being unreachable since its supposed to be `domain.com/page-name`.

Is there a way to change the address, where that page is located without having access to file server?

I only have access to WordPress website admin itself.

This happened after changing my site address from `domain.com/en` to `domain.com` and only that 1 page didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly go to the settings and try changing the Permalink settings.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem